# add ldap user to existing openldap server

Tags: openldap

I try to add a user to an existing and running openldap server. The server was setup by someone else (who is difficult to reach...) and is actively being used. Now I would like to add a new user, but get stuck with insufficient access.

The command I tried for adding a user is the following:

```
ldapadd -H ldap://servername -D "cn=admin,ou=..." -W -f ldap-userfile
```

The response I get is

```
adding new entry "cn=username,ou=..."
ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
    additional info: no write access to parent
```

The info to use in the above command I got from

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL uid=*
```

and this was the only one with `admin` in the name.

Note: I am root on the server where ldap is installed, so I can do pretty much anything. The only thing I should avoid is permanently changing any passwords, as others have to perform some tasks as well.

I did have a look at /etc/openldap, but to no avail. I have no clue about openldap, so it does not help me. Under `/etc/openldap/certs/password` I can find a password, but I have no idea of what to use with it.

If it helps: The server is running CentOS 6.10, openldap version is 2.4.40.

**EDIT: SOLVED**
See my own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it solved by using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60522370/4355191).

To summarize:
I got which id to use with

```
ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -Q -H ldapi:/// -LLL -o ldif-wrap=no -b cn=config '(objectClass=olcDatabaseConfig)' olcAccess
```

and then ran

```
ldapadd -H ldapi://servername -D "cn=Manager,..." -W -f ldapfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a LDIF file for New User
The following is a sample LDIF file that will be used to create a new user.

```
# cat adam.ldif
dn: uid=adam,ou=users,dc=tgs,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
cn: adam
uid: adam
uidNumber: 16859
gidNumber: 100
homeDirectory: /home/adam
loginShell: /bin/bash
gecos: adam
userPassword: {crypt}x
shadowLastChange: 0
shadowMax: 0
shadowWarning: 0
```

Now, use `ldapadd` command and the above `ldif` file to create a new user called `adam` in our OpenLDAP directory as shown below:

```
# ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=ramesh,dc=tgs,dc=com" -f adam.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "uid=adam,ou=users,dc=tgs,dc=com"
```

Comment: That does not work. Using "cn=ramesh..." obviously fails with `ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)` and using the existing "cn=admin..." fails with `ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)`, as described in the post.